# Redis not starting on centos 7

Tags: redis, centos, centos7

I am migrating my current ec2 environment from amazon linux to centos 7. There have been a few hurdles along the way but I have managed to tweak things here and there and get everything to work. However, I am not stuck on redis.

I have a small redis cluster running as a simple k/v cache. For this migration I have been following [these instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-redis-cluster-on-centos-7). The install seems to work fine but I check the status in systemctl and see the following:

```
$ sudo systemctl status redis.service
● redis.service - Redis persistent key-value database
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/redis.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/redis.service.d
           └─limit.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2016-02-26 16:57:43 UTC; 5s ago
  Process: 11680 ExecStop=/usr/bin/redis-shutdown (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 11678 ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis.conf --daemonize no (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 11678 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

The redis.log is created but empty so it is failing very early on. But I cannot seem to find the cause. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns-out that the redis.conf I was putting in-place via ansible using a jinja template was out-of-date. It was causing redis to not start. Would be nice if this was better outlined in the logs. Something like "missing or invalid configuration".